# How to call a function inside another function using jquery onclick event

Tags: jquery, onclick

How to call a function inside another function using jquery onclick event

my code is:

```js
 function function_one()
    {
       
    function function_two()
    {
        alert("Activate this function with the onclick event")
    }

        
    }
```

```html
<input onclick="function_two()">
```

Comment: please make your snippet properly in your snippet button there is no input type you define

Answer (score 0):

Define the function outside, then call it by its name;

```
function function_one()
{
  function_two();
}

function function_two()
{
    alert("Activate this function with the onclick event")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do this. It may help you

check the snippet

```js
function function_one() {
 
    
    function function_two() { 
        alert (name);   
    }
    function_two();    
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click me"  onclick="function_one()">
```